# trying to go from one form to another in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, forms

I am making a project on my own to practice what I've learned about MEAN stack. In the project I want the user to fill in a form and after it is saved in the database the system to take a use to a second form to fill it in etc. I am angularjs for the front end, and within it I am using ui.route. For some reason my program doesn't go to the second program. I already read about  other people with the same problem and I can't find what is wrong with my algorithm. Every form works well by itself or when I Make a call from the toolbar.

Frontend.js

```
    angular
  .module('authApp',['auth0', 'angular-storage', 'angular-jwt', 'ngMaterial', 'ui.router', 
          'AdminUser', 'appProfile', 'appToolbar', 'Mod-Company', 'ModShow'])

  .config(function($provide, authProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $httpProvider, jwtInterceptorProvider,$mdThemingProvider){

/*    $mdThemingProvider.theme('docs-dark'); */
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
       .dark();

    $mdThemingProvider.alwaysWatchTheme(true);

   authProvider.init({
    domain: 'workflowjobs.auth0.com',
    clientID: 'SjzgRRh3w4ZEFRGLdglpJYvCPCkM189w'
   }); 

   jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = function(store) {
      return store.get('id_token');
   }

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

   $stateProvider
     .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'components/home/home.html'
     })
     .state('company', {
        url: '/company',
        templateUrl: 'components/company/company.html'
     })
     .state('singlecompany', {
        url: '/singlecompany',
        templateUrl: 'components/singlecompany/singlecompany.html'
     })
     .state('show', {
        url: '/show',
        templateUrl: 'components/show/show-form.html'
     })
     .state('ticket', {
        url: '/ticket',
        templateUrl: 'components/ticket/ticket.html'
     })          
     .state('useradmin', {
        url: '/useradmin',
        templateUrl: 'components/useradmin/useradmin.html'
     })
     .state('user', {
        url: '/user',
        templateUrl: 'components/user/user.html'
     })     
     .state('profile', {
        url: '/profile', 
        templateUrl: 'components/profile/profile.html',
        controller: 'profileController',
        controllerAs: 'user'    
     });
```

From the form I use the controller I need, display the form to be filled in by the user and then I call addcompany() after the user click on the button to save the document on the mongodb database.

```
<section class="table" ng-controller="CompanyCtrl">
   <form name="CompanyForm"> 
     ...  
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="company.name" size="40">
     ...
    <p><md-button class="md-raised md-primary md-hue-1" ng-click="addcompany()" aria-label="next">
```

Now in this code is where I have the problem. the $location.path('/adminuser') doesn't work:

```
    var app = angular.module('Mod-Company', []);

app.controller('CompanyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
                            function($scope,$http){

               var refresh = function() {
                             $http.get('http://localhost:3001/api/company').success(function(response){

                                               $scope.companylist = response; 
                                               $scope.company = "";    
                                               });
                                         };

                refresh();  



                $scope.addcompany = function(){
                       $http.post('http://localhost:3001/api/company', $scope.company).success(function(response) {

                                        refresh();   

                                    $location.path('/useradmin');   

                                         });
                                     $location.path('/useradmin');
                         };
```

Comment: Does it throw any specific error in console from Chrome, IE.. and so on? Also, if you open the developer tools and put a debug point inside your `addcompany`, is it called? I believe with this will be easier to find the problem

Comment: There is not error

Comment: Is the method being called if you debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$location.path('/useradmin');` try  `$state.go('useradmin');`.

If it is still not working, it will be easier to help you if you could share your code in a https://jsbin.com or https://plnkr.co

Comment: Thank you for helping Everton.